# is it called a knot?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> **[knot](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/knot_1?q=knot)**: a join made by tying together two pieces or ends of string, rope, etc.
>
> to tie a knot
>
> Tie the two ropes together with a knot.
>
> Tie a knot in the rope.
>
> (figurative) hair full of knots and tangles (= twisted in a way that
>   is difficult to comb)
>
> a tangled knot of arms and legs
>
> Sailors had to know lots of different knots.

Look at this balloon,

[image]

People blow air into the balloon & then tie its end to prevent the air escaping from it.

**Do we call it a knot?**

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason you thought this _shouldn't_ be called a knot? It also seems like a quick web search could have easily answered this.

Comment: The dictionary definition is not quite correct.  It is possible to tie a knot in one piece of rope, or use a knot to tie one piece of rope to a pole etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the configuration of the balloon's material that prevents the air from escaping from the balloon does count as a knot.